# How to integrate existing MVC 4 application with Umbraco 6.1.6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco6

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I want to use Umbraco CMS to manage contents. I have read several articles but not yet sure how to integrate both the application together? What are the best approach?

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully integrated my existing MVC 4 application with Umbraco. [This](http://www.systenics.com/blog/setting-up-umbraco-6-in-visual-studio-2012-for-mvc-development/) article helped me a lot.

Once it is created, I copied all my models, views, controllers and other project specific file to the integrated solution.

Comment: I tried to follow the page but cannot get the files to replace into the current project (Keyword form the article: Go to the Umbraco download website and download the latest recommended download file. ). Can you share the files to me? Thank you!